# Javascript Regex after specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have several Javascript strings (using jQuery). All of them follow the same pattern, starting with 'ajax-', and ending with a name. For instance 'ajax-first', 'ajax-last', 'ajax-email', etc.

How can I make a regex to only grab the string after 'ajax-'?

So instead of 'ajax-email', I want just 'email'.

Comment: It should be mentioned whether or not you are using this in a jQuery call, as that places certain limits on the possible solutions to your situation.

Comment: @Code Jockey : Sorry about that. It is jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a comment you made on another user's post, try the following:

```
var $li = jQuery(this).parents('li').get(0);
var ajaxName = $li.className.match(/(?:^|\s)ajax-(.*?)(?:$|\s)/)[1];
```

Demo can [be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/SkPVF/)

---

**Below kept for reference only**

```
var ajaxName = 'ajax-first'.match(/(\w+)$/)[0];
alert(ajaxName);
```

Use the `\w` (word) pattern and bind it to the end of the string. This will force a grab of everything past the last hyphen (assuming the value consists of only [upper/lower]case letters, numbers or an underscore).

The non-regex approach could also use the [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method, coupled with [`Array.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

```
var parts = 'ajax-first'.split('-');
var ajaxName = parts.pop();
alert(ajaxName);
```

Comment: this would break if the string were `ajax-first-name` or similar, by only capturing the last group of letters, numbers, or underscores.

Comment: @CodeJockey: Agreed, which is why I included a disclaimer.

Comment: Even after reviewing your answer, I still don't see a disclaimer that addresses my concern that your code grabs the string after the last hyphen, rather than "grab the string after 'ajax-'?" as the asker specified

Comment: Would you mind linking to or quoting the other user's post (for context)?

Comment: @CodeJockey: It was the comment (with code sample) made in a comment to @Styrr's answer. After I saw it trying to be parsed from the `className` property, and may not be a class name on-its-own, I decided to take a different regex approach.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need RegEx for this. If your prefix is always "ajax-" then you just can do this:

```
var name = string.substring(5);
```

Comment: Good call. But when i try it, i get the following error. `Object ajax-first has no method 'substring'` Im new to javascript, so im not sure how to fix this... Heres my code. `var $class = jQuery(this).parents('li').attr('class').match(/ajax-[\w]+/);
                 alert( $class.substring(5) );`

Comment: Though this answer represents the truth of the situation, it is _*NOT*_ an answer to the question asked.

Comment: alert(jQuery(this).parents('li').attr('class').substring(5)); That should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to replace `ajax-` with `""`

Comment: Came across this when reviewing; it was flagged for low-quality. Might want to elaborate.

Comment: I think many users will appreciate if you could add more details, say, why this is possible and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I like the split method @Brad Christie mentions, but I would just do

```
function getLastPart(str,delimiter) {
  return str.split(delimiter)[1];
}
```

This works if you will always have only two-part strings separated by a hyphen. If you wanted to generalize it for any particular piece of a multiple-hyphenated string, you would need to write a more involved function that included an index, but then you'd have to check for out of bounds errors, etc.